# Constraint image is changing size

Tags: android, imageview

I have the following layout:

[image]

As you can see, the image is constraint and has the scale type `fitXY`. I've customized his size using percentage as you can see on the following code:

```
<ImageView
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3" app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
        android:id="@+id/book_image"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/text_view_default" android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

But this is the result that I obtain when executing:

[image]
[image]

Why is changing the size?

**EDIT:**

I've seen that in some books the text of the description exceeds the limit of the screen, so you can scroll and I understand that the percentage I'm setting is for the whole view, not just the visible piece.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you are setting your layout_height and layout_width properties to be 0dp. Doing this will tell the view that it should stretch as much as it can. You should be using wrap_content or even a fixed size if all of your images should look the same (dimensions).

Comment: My image height and width is set here: `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"` and `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"`

Comment: Have you tried to change the flag of your scale type for, lets say, centerCrop for example?

Comment: Try android:adjustViewBounds = "true";